# Simulate spring wire through fixed points

Tags: physics, simulation

Suppose we have a wire made of an ideal spring steel. If we bend it and then release any external force it will straighten itself into a perfect line.

Suppose also that the wire is attached to some set of points in the plane. The wire can rotate in these points slide through the points but can not escape out of these points.

How to simulate this?

I made a code when we have only two fixed points - (large points in image). The small points are ends of the wire. The length of wire is constant all the time.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{x^2, 1/a x^2 + 1 - 1/a}, {x, -5, 5}, 
  Epilog -> {Point[{{b /. 
        FindRoot[
         b Sqrt[1 + (4 b^2)/a^2] + 1/2 a ArcSinh[(2 b)/a] - 
          1/2 (4 Sqrt[17] + ArcSinh[4]), {b, 1}], 
       1/a b^2 + 1 - 1/a /. 
        FindRoot[
         b Sqrt[1 + (4 b^2)/a^2] + 1/2 a ArcSinh[(2 b)/a] - 
          1/2 (4 Sqrt[17] + ArcSinh[4]), {b, 1}]}, {-b /. 
        FindRoot[
         b Sqrt[1 + (4 b^2)/a^2] + 1/2 a ArcSinh[(2 b)/a] - 
          1/2 (4 Sqrt[17] + ArcSinh[4]), {b, 1}], 
       1/a b^2 + 1 - 1/a /. 
        FindRoot[
         b Sqrt[1 + (4 b^2)/a^2] + 1/2 a ArcSinh[(2 b)/a] - 
          1/2 (4 Sqrt[17] + ArcSinh[4]), {b, 1}]}}], 
    Point[{{-2, 4}, {2, 4}}], PointSize -> Large, 
    Point[{{-1, 1}, {1, 1}}]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {-1, 5}], {a, 1, 100}]
```

[image]

This is only a pseudo simulation and it has nothing to do with reality, I only wanted to demonstrate how it might look.

Instead of two fixed points we can have 3, 4 or more points. I have no idea how to simulate it.

Comment: You could assume that the restoring force is proportional to the curvature (parametrized by length) and you have mass. This gives you two second order ODE.

Comment: I think it the shape of wire would be independent of its mass and its strength.

Comment: I assumed you want the temporal evolution. If you want the equilibrium, then this is given by minimizing the potential energy of the bending. If I remember correctly, splines will do this.

Comment: To have physical sense, the wire could be modeled as a Bernoulli uniform beam, considering linear deformations domain. This model produces similar conditions as appear in cubic spline interpolation.

Comment: This is a standard problem along the lines of large amplitude beam vibration. Small amplitude beam vibration is well covered by the Bernoulli theory.  For large amplitudes, issues you have to consider are i) does tension along the wire have to be considered and ii) do higher order terms in the strain need to be included. If you want a simple answer then just assume that linear theory will be a good approximation for your large amplitudes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to interpolate four points with a polynom of order 4. Becuase there are 4 interpolation conditions to evaluate 5 parameters one parameter might be specified.

```
p = {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {2, 4}, {-2, 4}}
poly = Function[x, a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4]  
sol = Solve[Map[poly[#[[1]]] == #[[2]] &, p], {a, b, c, d, e}][[1]]
Show[ Plot[Table[poly[x] /. sol, {a, {-1, 0, 1}}], {x, -3, 3},Evaluated -> True], ListPlot[p]]
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure that this way would real wire behave.